# Supremum of something positive

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\geq1$. Is it true that taking the supremum of $k$ is the same as letting $k$ go to infinity, and thus $\mathrm{sup}\{k\}=\infty$?

Comment: Usually, you ask about the supremum for a sequence like $\frac{5}{i}, i=1,2,3...$. But I think your example is also OK

Comment: This is an argument I stumbled upon when looking at the proof of Fubini's theorem for double series. It however wasn't made clear how one should interpret the supremum of $k\geq 1$, so I was just wondering, if the argumentation above is correct or not. :)

Comment: It is a relatively common convention to define the supremum of sets that are unbounded above, such as $[1, \infty)$, to be $\infty$. It's also relatively common to say $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$. On the other hand, sometimes we simply say that the supremum doesn't exist in these cases. Check which convention you're using when reading a proof, or clarify which one you're using when writing a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{x: x\geq 1\}=[1,\infty)$. The notation $\sup A=\infty$ is a fancy way of saying $A$ is unbounded from above. Put differently, the set of upper bounds for $A$ is the empty set. But $\sup A =\infty$ is a quick way of saying this. It's also useful in a more complicated setting (like a research problem) where it may be unclear that a set is unbounded until you do some calculations.

In some sense, it's fairly natural to say $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$ and $\inf \emptyset = \infty$ since this notation ensures that no weird calculations can go awry. Also note that for a set $A$, denote $U$ as the set of upper bounds. Then $\sup A=\inf U$ so if $A$ is unbounded, this becomes $\inf \emptyset=\infty$, which checks out.

Comment: I remember $\sup \emptyset = -\infty$ by every $M$ being an upper bound of the empty set (i.e. it is true that, for all $x \in \emptyset$, $x \le M$), so the least of these upper bounds is $-\infty$.

Comment: I like this method.